# How to measure color proximity / concentration in an image? (python solution preferred)

Tags: python, image, colors

Consider the 2 images below:
Image 1:
[image: a few big black things]

Image 2:
[image: lots of smaller black things]

For the sake of the argument let's say that the 2 images have the same amount of black pixels.

I would like to calculate the "concentration" of black pixels. I.e. image 1 has higher "index" than image 2, since the black pixels are more "grouped" or concentrated than in image 2.

Intuitively I would hope that a metric or function would already exist. I did some searches but couldn't quite find what I am looking for.

Applied to real examples, I would use kmeans to reduce color numbers to around 15 and apply that calculation to each color. I do not think that a histogram would help as I am assuming a same number of black pixels (pls correct me if I'm wrong).

One approach I can think of is:
1. Filter for color
2. Use contours to define blobs
3. Count size and number of blobs for each color
4. Quantify into a comparable metric per color
I'm not an expert in imaging libraries, so if you could provide some guidance on how to implement that, it would be great.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are heading towards the field of [Granulometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granulometry_(morphology)) with was developed by a Parisian mining company to determine the sizes of grains of minerals in rock in order to decide whether mining was viable.

Anyway, enough history. If you perform a *"morphological closing"* on each of your images with a disk as the structuring element, gradually increasing in radius, you will get a measure of the distribution of the sizes of blobs present in your image.

No time to write the Python at the minute, but the graph below shows your images side-by-side with a red vertical bar to separate them. In each successive frame of the video, I increase the radius of the circular disk-shaped structuring element by 1 pixel. The first frame has radius of 1, and the final frame has a radius of 39:

[image]

Hopefully you can see that the bigger, more concentrated shapes hang around longer than the smaller ones.

Comment: iWow. Interesting approach (also thanks for the background explanation). Would I have choice over the shape of the structuring element? Thanks